# opencv face recognition, get coordinates of "bounding box" around image

Tags: java, opencv, coordinates

today I was trying a project with opencv in java and I was following [this](https://blog.openshift.com/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers/) code. I modified it to work with opencv 3.0.0. Basically I'm trying to take a bunch of images from a folder and crop the pictures where the face recognition finds the face. So the problem is I can't seem to get the coordinates of the "bounding box" that goes around the image  ([bounding box](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/_images/faceDetection.png)). I want to crop the image to the box, does anyone know what I am talking about or what to do?

Any help is appreciated! :) I am a (*very*) beginner programmer. Thank you!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/Family/workspace/detect face/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Family\\Downloads\\Photos");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(listOfFiles[j]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length-1; i++){
        String picname = listOfFiles[i].toString();

        System.out.println("reading: " + listOfFiles[i]);

        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(picname);

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));


        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar (0, 255, 0));
        }


        String filename = "monkey.png";
        System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way..

```
rect.getX(); //for getting x cordinates
rect.getY(); //for getting y cordinates
rect.getWidth(); //for getting width
rect.getHeight(); //for getting height
```

This image will help you.

[image]

Comment: thank you! That pretty much solved it for me, :D I figured out the code after looking at what you said.

Comment: Go ahead ...All the best...Dont forget to share your problm..And also don't forget to vote your best answer..

Comment: Be careful... the width **includes** the leftmost coordinate. `x <= pt.x < x+width` **not** `<= x+width`, and likewise for the height (documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Rect.html)). As noted in the documentation, you can confirm this using `rect.contains()`.